# ArborText/how to open multiple xml files in one window

Tags: xml

Is there any way I can open 4+ XML files under the same window?

ArborText can open the files as separated window, but I'm looking for a way that I can open more than 4+ XML files in one window.

Answer (score 0):

AE doesn't have "tab" view with multiple documents like a browser.